# How to make an if not statement?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I’m making a shop where you can buy something with emeralds. If you can afford it, it plays the mob.villager.yes sound. But if you can’t afford it, it plays the mob.villager.no sound. How do I script the “can’t afford” part?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you edit your post to include the command?

Comment: It tried using redstone torches. But it didn't work

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out. You have to use scoreboards instead of real items.

Comment: Somebody else could have your same problem, you should explain your solution with more details.